# Angular 6 Headers authorization and charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, mean-stack

I have a couple questions in 1.

Here is the code I am using:

weather.service.ts:

```
'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';   

let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class WeatherService {


  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  dailyForcast() {
    return this._http.get('http://history.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=London,UK', {headers})
.pipe(map(result => result));
 }
}
`
```

Then I have the component:

```
import { WeatherService } from './../../weather.service';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-backtesting',
  templateUrl: './backtesting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./backtesting.component.css']
})
export class BacktestingComponent implements OnInit {
  LineChart = [];
  constructor( private _weather: WeatherService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._weather.dailyForcast()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

}
```

Then we have the error:

```
ERROR Object { headers: Object, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized",   url: "http://history.openweathermap.org/d…", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://hi…", error: Object }
```

This error seems out of place. At the above link, we are able to pull the json information with no problem.

Here is the output from the above link. All of this is a test for the next part, graphing this data using chartjs. No credentials are required to view. I plan to use 2 API's. 1 requires auth the other does not.

```
{"message":"","cod":"200","city_id":2643743,"calctime":0.0875,"cnt":3,"list":[{"main":{"temp":279.946,"temp_min":279.946,"temp_max":279.946,"pressure":1016.76,"sea_level":1024.45,"grnd_level":1016.76,"humidity":100},"wind":{"speed":4.59,"deg":163.001},"clouds":{"all":92},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"rain":{"3h":2.69},"dt":1485717216},{"main":{"temp":282.597,"temp_min":282.597,"temp_max":282.597,"pressure":1012.12,"sea_level":1019.71,"grnd_level":1012.12,"humidity":98},"wind":{"speed":4.04,"deg":226},"clouds":{"all":92},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"rain":{"3h":0.405},"dt":1485745061},{"main":{"temp":279.38,"pressure":1011,"humidity":93,"temp_min":278.15,"temp_max":280.15},"wind":{"speed":2.6,"deg":30},"clouds":{"all":90},"weather":[{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"},{"id":741,"main":"Fog","description":"fog","icon":"50d"}],"dt":1485768552}]}
```

I am looking to understand why this error happened and what the fix is. I am also looking for resources on chartjs and calling an API with a service in angular 6. I have worked through many tutorials and all of them seem to stop short of my solutions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it seems that the service you are calling needs a sort of authorization, usually realized with a token. do you know something about that?

Comment: openweather api takes auth token , you need to pass an auth api key in the header for testing purpose. you can get it at the demo page

Comment: I just tried to exchange the existing url to: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=1111111111


I am going to sign up for a key. 
The actual service I want to use is: https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets I have similar issues...

Comment: the error there is:
ERROR Object { headers: Object, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for (unknown …", error: error }  vendor.js:55988:5
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Am I missing something when pulling from https?

Comment: I assume then I use cors... how is it actually used. Is it just me, or does the Angular 6 Docs are not the best.

Comment: Anyone have an answer for this?